# How to use selectById selector generated from createEntityAdapter

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

All examples on redux-toolkit website show usage of either `selectIds` or `selectAll`.
Using either of them is simple. I have a `redux-slice` from where I am exporting

```
export const {
  selectById: selectUserById,
  selectIds: selectUserIds,
  selectEntities: selectUserEntities,
  selectAll: selectAllUsers,
  selectTotal: selectTotalUsers
} = usersAdapter.getSelectors(state => state.users)
```

then I am importing the selectors in my components and using like

```
const valueIAmInterestedIn = useSelector(selectUserIds)
```

I am interested in the code related to the usage of `selectUserById`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter#return-value) the by id selector has the following signature: `selectById: (state: V, id: EntityId) => T | undefined`.

So you can call it in your component in the following way:

```
const Component = ({ id }) => {
  const item = useSelector((state) =>
    selectUserById(state, id)
  );
};
```

This implementation of "normalization" may not work if you sort/filter entities on the server because the state would look more like:

```
{
  data: {
    entityType: {
      //query is key and value is status and result
      //  of the api request
      'sort=name&page=1': {
        loading: false,
        requested: true,
        error: false,
        stale: false,
        ids: [1, 2],
      },
      'sort=name:desc&page=1': {
        //would have loading, requested ....
        ids: [2, 1],
      },
      data: {
        //all the data (fetched so far)
        '1': { id: 1 },
        '2': { id: 2 },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I have not worked with the "helpers" so have to look into it as it may facilitate for server side filtering and sorting.

I also doubt it will memoize the selector:

```
const List = ({ items }) => (
  <ul>
    {items.map(({ id }) => (
      <Item key={id} id={id} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);
const Item = React.memo(function Item({ id }) {
  //selectUserById is called with different id during
  // a render and nothing will be memoized
  const item = useSelector((state) =>
    selectUserById(state, id)
  );
});
```

I have created a short documentation on how you can use [selectors](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) created with reselect.

Answer (score 3):

Selector can be created on top of `selectById` as below:

```
export const getLanguageById = (entityId: number) => {
  return createSelector(selectLanguageState, (state) =>
    selectById(state, entityId)
  );
};
```

This can be used in your component as below:

```
const language = useSelector(languageSelectors.getLanguageById(18));
```

I guess it's more straightforward and easy to read/ understand.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for when using multiple entity adapter in one reducer! Thanks a lots!